# An idiom for "making one's final / last attempt / effort"

Tags: idioms, expressions, idioms-in-context

I am wondering what are the nuances among the following options and whether they all work properly in this sentence:

- After so much work, just keep it up a little longer! You've got this far. If I were you, I would make a .......

a. final push 
b. [last-ditch effort](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+last-ditch+effort) 
c. [shoot one's bolt](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shoot+your+bolt)

I need to imply the last effort through an idiom in AmE.
It seems that the idiom "[shoot one's bolt](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-shot-your-bolt)" is more common in BrE, but I need a purely AmE idiom. Also, according to the [Longman dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/have-shot-your-bolt), "shoot one's wad" has been introduced as the American alternative for the British version "shoot one's bolt". However, I have no idea if it works in this sense in common, everyday American speeches.

Many thanks

Comment: (BrE speaker) I've never heard the "shoot one's bolt" expression.

Comment: **Shoot one's wad** has acquired a sexual connotation that coexists with the meaning you have cited. Knowing when you shouldn't use it might require years of experience.

Comment: To have ***shot one's bolt*** is something said ***after*** making a [final ***or*** only] effort / contribution, so it's not relevant here. The main difference between making a ***final push*** and a ***last-ditch effort*** is that the former nearly always ***confidently*** refers to what's expected to be a ***successful*** (albeit *arduous*) endeavour, whereas the latter is generally restricted to ***pessimistic*** contexts with a perceived high chance of total ***failure.***

Comment: You might wish to compare 'go for broke', 'pull out all the stops', 'all or nothing', 'swan song', 'forlorn hope'. 'make or break', 'do or die', 'grand finale', 'last act'...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the intention is to encourage the person to keep persevering until the job is finished, I would choose *make a final push.*

*Make a last-ditch effort* implies that the person has been failing up to now but might just manage to succeed at the last moment.

If you have *shot your bolt*, you have already used up all your resources and have no chance of succeeding.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "Go big or go home" comes to mind, as in

- After so much work, just keep it up a little longer! You've got this far. If I were you, I would go big or go home.

Even though the phrase implies a choice, the implication is that one should not quit (or "go home") and therefore one should give it a final intense effort ("go big")

I think the phrase also implies finality, because if you "go big" (attempt again with maximum effort) and still fail, you aren't likely to be able to go bigger again after that.